# Elasticsearch: Waiting for Long Running requests to complete

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, nest

What is the best approach for knowing when a **long running** Elasticsearch request is complete?

Today I have a process that periodically purges ~100K documents from an AWS hosted ES that contains a total of ~60M documents.

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("https://mycompany.es.aws.com"));
settings.RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)); // not sure this helps

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var request = new DeleteByQueryRequest("MyIndex") { ... };

// this call will return an IsValid = true, httpstatus = 504 after ~60s,
var response = await client.DeleteByQueryAsync(request);
```

Even with timeout set to 3 minutes, the call always returns in ~60s with an empty response and a 504 status code.  Though through Kibana, I can see that the delete action continues (and properly completes) over the next several minutes.

Is there a better way to request and monitor (wait for completion) a long running ES request?

**UPDATE**

Based on Simon Lang's response I updated my code to make use of ES Tasks.  The final solution looks something like this...

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("https://mycompany.es.aws.com"));
settings.RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)); // not sure this helps

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var request = new DeleteByQueryRequest("MyIndex") 
{
  Query = ...,
  WaitForCompletion = false
};

var response = await client.DeleteByQueryAsync(request);

if (response.IsValid)
{
  var taskCompleted = false;
  while (!taskCompleted)
  {
    var taskResponse = await client.GetTaskAsync(response.Task);
    taskCompleted = taskResponse.Completed;

    if (!taskCompleted)
    {
      await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @LeBigCat that the timeout comes from AWS and it is not a NEST problem.

But to address your question:
The `_delete_by_query` request supports the `wait_for_completion` parameter. If you set it to `false`, the request returns immediately with a task id. You then can request the task status by the task api.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html

Comment: I wasn't aware of the Task concept in ES.  Thanks.  This definitely solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This isnot a nest - elastic problem, the default timeout in nest query is 0 (no timeout).

You got timeout from amazon server (60s default)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-error-message.html

This link explain everything you need to know :)

Comment: I had wondered if that was occurring given the 504 error.  Looks I could use KeepAlive as a work-around.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @Simon Lang's answer, this is also the case with the _update_by_query api. For those unfamiliar with the _tasks api, you can query for your task in Kibana. The string returned by the update or delete by query will be of the form:

```
{
   "tasks" : "nodeId:taskId"
}
```

and you can view the status of the task using this command in Kibana:

```
GET _tasks/nodeId:taskId
```